# Converting id to class in Javascript

Tags: javascript

How to convert all this that all divs have class instead of id?
i am new in this world and for now just copy paste code and learning...

```
    <div id="LEGEND">abB</div>

<div id="small-a" style="display: none;">This is small-a</div> 
<div id="small-b" style="display: none;">This is small-b</div> 
<div id="big-a" style="display: none;">This is big-a</div> 
<div id="big-b" style="display: none;">This is big-b</div>

<script>
function showElement(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
}

window.onload = function ShowHide() {
    var legend = document.getElementById("LEGEND").innerHTML;

    if(legend.indexOf("a") != -1) showElement("small-a");
    if(legend.indexOf("b") != -1) showElement("small-b");
    if(legend.indexOf("A") != -1) showElement("big-a");
    if(legend.indexOf("B") != -1) showElement("big-b");
}
</script>
```

Comment: why you want to convert it?

Comment: Open the file in notepad. Press Ctrl+H. Type `id="` in Find what text box. Type `class="` in Replace with text box. Click Replace All. Close the dialog box and save the file.

Comment: Put `.textContent` before `.indexOf`. You have no elements with classes, and your first sentence is unclear, so I'm not sure what you need.

Comment: i want to see the same code as this but using classes instead of id, couse when i just replace id with class thing dont work.

Comment: Why would you want to convert it? Even your script uses ids, not classes, so it would break when you change the attributes.

Comment: when i add id to this certian div in my script something go vrong.

Comment: Now i change code i am sory but wrong code i paste.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you're trying to do this programmatically, but anyway:

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('div');

[...elements].forEach(el => {
  if (el.id) {
    el.classList.add(el.id);
    el.removeAttribute('id');
  }
});
```

```css
.foo {
  background: tomato;
}

.bar {
  background: gold;
}

.baz {
  background: indianred;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">Foo</div>
<div id="bar">Bar</div>
<div id="baz">Baz</div>
```

Comment: want to know how instead of function showElement(id) make the same but for class